# Get Woocommerce Subscription Start Date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

I realize this may full well be a total novice question but at this point I'm so frustrated I don't even care. I'm trying to create a variable with the current users subscription start date - if they have one - and I'm stuck at pulling in the start date.

This is what I have so far - it won't be a shortcode in the end (it will be a variable I put into a function) I've just got it set up as a shortcode so I can see the output - and it returns the whole array of the users stored info. I'm just after the start date :)

```
function subscriber_start_date(){
    $start_date = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscription( $user_id, 'start_date' );
    print_r($start_date);
}

add_shortcode("subscriber-start-date","subscriber_start_date");
```

I've looked at the documents [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/data-structure/#section-2) and [here](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/management-functions/) but am still just drawing up nothing on this and I know it's going to be something stupid simple like adding a variable somewhere, a comma,  or [''] - I've tried a myriad of combinations of things that make sense to me but nothing is working (this is the only combination that's returned anything of use).

Any HELPFUL comments would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth mentioning a few things:

First, this isn't Core WooCommerce, it's an add-on (Subscriptions).

Second, the documentation you linked to says specifically:

> ...each subscription is returned as an array with the following values...

That means the function isn't going to return just the start date.

Put another way, the second field is a *subscription identifier*.  A user can have more than one subscription.  This function allows you to get a specific *subscription*, not a specific field from the subscription.

So, in order to do what you want, you need to add to your code as follows:

```
function subscriber_start_date() {
    // NOTE: You don't have the $user_id - are you setting it?

    // Somehow you need to identify the subscription you want.
    $subscription_id = 'MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID';
    $subscription = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscription( $user_id, $subscription_id );

    $start_date = (isset($subscription['start_date'])) ? $subscription['start_date'] : FALSE;

    var_dump($start_date);
}

add_shortcode("subscriber-start-date","subscriber_start_date");
```

If you do NOT know the subscription ID, then you could do something like this to get the "first" subscription for the user:

```
function subscriber_start_date() {
    // Set start date to initial value
    $start_date = FALSE;
    // Get ALL subscriptions
    $subscriptions = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscriptions( $user_id );
    if ($subscriptions) {
        // Get the first subscription
        $subscription = array_shift($subscriptions);
        // Get the start date, if set
        $start_date = (isset($subscription['start_date'])) ? $subscription['start_date'] : FALSE;
    }

    return $start_date;
}
```

Comment: Thank for the very helpful, respectful, timely and thorough response! I guess I missed how it was returned when I was frantically just looking for a way to make it work - that said I probably still wouldn't have gotten to the proper end coding that you provided.

I didn't have the user id set, by default if left with no value it fills for current user I believe? For the function I'm looking to write, I'm just looking to see if they have any subscription (and they will only be allowed to have 1 subscription at a time).